# Qt 5.3.1: Why do I need to set include path and libs for widgets

Tags: qt

I'm on Windows 8.1. I want to build Qt apps from the command line like the Unix trooper I usually am. Well, actually, I want things to be a little more automated! After wondering why qmake would not generate the proper Makefiles and hand-editing them, I finally realized I could just add on to the Qt variable in the Qt .pro file. (Been since about Qt 3-something that I've Qt'ed, so finally the light-bulb went on :)
This is the simplest of applications to help refresh the dead brain cells.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The .pro file:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Sat Aug 23 16:38:04 2014
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = HelloQt
INCLUDEPATH += .

#why do I need these
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtwidgets"
LIBS += "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5widgets.lib"

#why does the following line do nothing
qmake: Qt += widgets 

CONFIG -= X86

# Input
SOURCES += hello.cpp
```

Why do I need to specify the widgets INCLUDEPATH and LIBS to get a successful build?
As far as I can tell, Qt += widgets is not a valid addition to the Qt variable.
Why not? If I don't specify the Qt5Widgets include and libs, and I run nmake, I get errors related to not finding the include for QApplication and/or linker errors.
With those two lines in the .pro file everything works fine. Has anybody run into this sort of thing, am I missing something?

Comment: The line does nothing because it only works if the `qmake` configuration is set. It normally isn't. I don't know where did you get the idea of this "qmake: " prefix, but it's wrong. And capitalization matters. The beginning of that line should be: `QT += ...`. It'll work then.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I was looking at some 4.8 documentation, however, Qt 5 uses widgets instead of gui.

Comment: What you wrote wouldn't work for any version of Qt.

Comment: Yes it did, QT ignored the "qmake: QT += widgets" line and included widgets from the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS lines, which is exactly the effect of QT += widgets.

Comment: I simply mean that the line you wrote doesn't do anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should look more like `QT += core gui widgets`. This will set the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Kuba. I believe only widgets is needed since you get core and gui for free.